# For two points $A, B$ on a line $L$, show that there exist two points $P$ such that $PA = e\times PB $ for $e>0$ and $e \ne 1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

> Let $\rm A, B$ be distinct points on a line $L$, and let $e$ be a positive constant. By parametrizing $L$ show that when $e \neq 1$ there exist two distinct points $\rm P$ for which ${\rm P A} = e{\rm P B}$, and that when $e = 1$ there is just one.

Let $\rm A =(x_1, y_1)\, B = (x_2, y_2)$, Then $$\mathrm{L}(t) = \big((1-t)x_1 + tx_2, (1-t)y_1 + ty_2  \big)$$

Now if I let ${\rm P} = (a, b)$ and ${\rm P}' = (c, d)$,

Then $$\mathrm {\dfrac{PA}{PB}} = \dfrac{\sqrt{(x_1 - a)^2 + (y_1 - b)^2}}{\sqrt{(x_2 - a)^2 + (y_2 - b)^2}} = e \tag 1$$

I have to prove that $\mathrm{\dfrac{P^\prime A}{P' B}} = e$ for $e \ne 1$.

I tried brute force method by expanding $\mathrm{\dfrac{P' A}{P' B}}$ in distance formula form and equating it to $(1)$ but it does not work, I just end up in a mess.

Also I don't have any idea how to use the parametric form of line here. I think $\rm P^\prime$ would be the reflection of $\rm P$ by the line $L$, but I don't know how to prove it.

Any hints ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making heavy weather of this. Write $\vec a$ for the position
vector of $A$ and write $\vec u$ for the vector $\vec {AB}$.
Then a typical point on  the line joining $A$ and $B$ has position vector
$\vec a+t\vec u$. The $|AP|=|t|\,|AB|$ and $|BP|=|1-t|\,|AB|$. So $|AP|
=e|BP|$ iff $|t|=e|1-t|$ iff $t=\pm e(1-t)$ etc.